# How do I convert every nth column to row?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I'm looking at this macro:

```
Sub Spl_Transpose() 
Dim i, LastRow 
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
For i = LastRow To 1 Step -2 
Cells(i, "A").Offset(-1, 1).Value = Cells(i, "A").Value 
Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete 
Next 
End Sub
```

The above macro turns every other column into a row.

I have created a long, `3-field CSV in Excel`.  I want every `1st column` to go in `A`, every `2nd column` to go in `B`, and every `3rd column` to go in `C`.  Can anyone tell me how to transform the above macro and make it happen?

Example input:

```
     A        B       C          D        E           F          G         H           I          J         K        L          
1    fruit    bowl    kitchen    bread    breadbox    kitchen    cereal    cupboard    kitchen    stereo    floor    living room
```

And example output:

```
A       B      C
fruit   bowl   kitchen
bread   breadbox   kitchen
cereal   cupboard   kitchen
stereo   floor   living room
```

I'm wondering what needs to be changed in order to increase this to an `A    B    C    D` scenario, also.

Comment: Can you give an example of the data and the output, please?

Comment: ^^ Can I get my rep back now, dude?

Comment: I didn't down vote your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you're asking, you need to iterate over four things:

1. The rows in your original dataset
2. The cells (columns) in each rows
3. The destination sheet rows (as you paste data there)
4. The destination sheet columns (as you paste data there)

So we create two loops, one loop to loop through the original dataset rows, and one to loop through the cells in that row.

Then we use two counters to keep track of the destination sheet's rows so that we can move to the next row once one has been filled with three cells.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
'This example places the data (output) on Sheet2.
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim i1 As Long
Dim i2 As Long
Dim i3 As Long
Dim i4 As Long
Dim lFields As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

lField = Application.InputBox("Please enter the number of fields.", _
         "Number of Fields", Type:=1) 

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")   'Dataset sheet.
Set sht = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")  'Destination sheet.
lastRow = ws.Range("A:A").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
i3 = 1
i4 = 1

For i1 = lastRow To 1 Step -1 'Loop through rows.
    lastCol = ws.Rows("" & i1 & ":" & i1 & "").Find("*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    For i2 = 1 To lastCol 'Loop through cells in row.
        sht.Cells(i3, i4) = ws.Cells(i1, i2).Value
        If sht.Cells(i3, lField) <> vbNullString Then i3 = i3 + 1 'Stay on row until third _
                                                             'column (field) is full. _ 
                                                             'To add a column, change _
                                                             '".Cells(i3,3)" to ".Cells(i3,4)"
        i4 = i4 + 1
        If i4 = lField + 1 Then i4 = 1 '<~~ This is what controls how many columns are _
                              '    in the output. To add a column (field), change _ 
                              '    "If i4 = 4" to "If i4 = 5".
    Next i2
Next i1

End Sub
```

This example loops from the bottom of your dataset to the top, but can be easily modified to go from top to bottom by changing the first loop from

```
For i1 = lastRow To 1 Step -1
```

to

```
For i1 = 1 To lastRow
```

Comment: It's confusing to me: why do you loop from the bottom instead of the top?  I'm not accustomed to this concept in programming.

Comment: I wrote it that way because the code in your question is coded the same way and I decided to keep it the same. Most of the time one does it (from an Excel point of view) when deleting rows. When looping top to bottom, if a row is deleted, the next row can be skipped as the other rows slide up to replace the deleted row.

Comment: I'm also curious: why `range(A:A)`?  Why not just `A`, in this case?  From A to A?  Doesn't that seem needlessly redundant?  Again, forgive me, I"m not a very advanced programmer.

Comment: ARich: how do we start a chat?  "one does it" meaning "one loops backwards"?  Or are you forward-referencing 'top-to-bottom'?  I want to really emphasize: what I'm looking for in an answer is: *what do I change to increase/decrease the number of CSV fields*?

Comment: Have you tried my code on your dataset? (Save it first, of course.) The above code will work no matter how many fields you add. However, if you want the results to be grouped together like in the example output you gave, you'll need to add fields in multiples of three.

Comment: Well, it works...  I'm just having trouble answering that final question part: which part of the macro is responsible for the number of field.

Comment: I added a comment to the code in my answer. Does the comment answer your question?

Comment: I believe so.  I need to test it.  But essentially, in `sht.Cells(i3, 3)`, changing the second argument to 4 means '4 fields', and in `If i4 = 4 Then i4 = 1`, changing '= 4' to '= 5' means '4 columns in the output'.  I will try to add a generalized version of the code with an input dialog (just because I think it's good practice to generalize).  It's good to have the specific version, also, though.  I hope you can leave that up.  Thanks.

Comment: Added input box to the code so you can see how it would work. Hope that helps!